# Question about strings

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make my program check for bad user input.

In this case, I only want digits. (No alphabet, etc.)

```
if (someStringHere.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos)
```

Is it correct to say that this piece of code will give me the implementation to do so?

Based on my knowledge, this returns `true` if the string is only digits, and `false` if it finds something other than digits from 0-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation looks good to me.

The following isn't an exhaustive testcase, but it's enough to prove the point given that frankly it's obvious that your approach is good (assuming ASCII input).

```
<tomalak> geordi << isAllNums("12345"), isAllNums("a3234e"), isAllNums("abcdef"); bool isAllNums(const std::string& str) { return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos; }
<geordi> true, false, false
```

---

- http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/geordi/

Comment: Oh yep! It looks like it works but I just have a quick question. find_first_not_of returns the position of the first character it is being matched against according to cplusplus.com

Why does it work in this bool equation?

Comment: @vincent: Because if you get a position back, that position does not equal `std::string::npos` (which is also a "position", albeit a "pseudo-position" that can never represent a _real_ position in your string).

Comment: Strings are funny. They use indexes (and the `npos` invalid pseudo-index) in place of iterators. Just go with it ;)